# How to gunzip all the files with a given extension and send to another folder?

Tags: bash, gunzip

I have a folder with 28 gz files with the extension `.gz` and 28 files with the extension `.gz.bam`.

I would like to unzip all the 28 `.gz` files and send them to another folder. I was doing one by one as follows:

```
gunzip -c file1.gz > /mnt/s3/data_transfer/file1
```

How can I specify I want the .gz and not the .gz.bam?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
for f in *.gz; do gunzip -c "$f" > /mnt/s3/data_transfer/"${f%.gz}"; done
```

You may remove the `.gz` files by `rm *.gz` after that, if you want.
Or, alternatively

```
cp *.gz /mnt/s3/data_transfer/ && cd /mnt/s3/data_transfer && gunzip *.gz
```

Note that the latter command will `gunzip` all `.gz` files in the directory `/mnt/s3/data_transfer`, including the ones that exist, if any, before the `cp` command is executed. If you want to remove the original `.gz` files, replace `cp` with `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's find the files:

```
find . -type f -name "*.gz" > foo.sh
```

We find the files whose name ends with **gz** and save them into **foo.sh**. Let's open it:

```
vim foo.sh
```

Now, we prepend the `gunzip` command to each line. Let's hit the `:` key, so at the bottom of the file you can enter a command. Now, let's enter this command:

```
%s/^/gunzip -c /
```

this replaces the start of each line with the text we want to prepend.

Then we append the destination path, by pressing `:` again and pasting the following:

```
%s/$/ \/some\/path/
```

of course, instead of `\/some\/path` you will need to use your own path.

Finally, add

```
cd /some/path
rename 's/\.gz//' *
```

to remove all the gz extensions from the files in **/some/path** (replace this with your actual path)

Note that you may need to install `rename` and here I assumed that the target path already existed.